# AWS Load balancer security group is missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, security

My AWS load balancer suddenly lost all instances. They became unhealthy because it can't communicate with EC2 nodes. It turns out that security group of nodes is preventing load balancer to talk to them.

I am following [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-groups.html#assign-sg-console) to assign a security group to my load balancer. However, there's no security group section under the "description" section. Are there any recent AWS change that removes this?

Comment: What type of ELB do you have ? Does your EC2 instances security group allow incoming traffic on the health check port so that load balancer is able to do a health check on that port ? From the documentation - In both EC2-Classic and in a VPC, you must ensure that the security groups for your instances allow the load balancer to communicate with your instances on both the listener port and the health check port.

Comment: @ben5556 I think I am using classic ELB, not ALB. Yes, the problem I found is that the EC2 instances security group doesn't allow connection from ELB.  Both ELB and EC2 are inside the same VPC and the security group allows 10.0.0.0/16, which I think it allows all local network connections inside the same VPC. It was working. However, the network connection from ELB to EC2 instance was broken since Dec 5th, 2018. I then search for solutions and find AWS documentation says I need to add the ELB security group to EC2 security allowed list. However, there's no security group attached to my ELB.

Comment: Do you remember assigning a security group when creating your classic ELB ?